# Can i manually add EC2 instances to a already running cloudformation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Say i have already running cloudformation stack having 2 ec2 instances and 2 ec2 instances launched from console outside of the stack. I want to add these instances(console launched) to cloudformation stack. 
Can it be done by adding tags that are automatically added by cloudformation like

```
aws:cloudformation:logical-id
aws:cloudformation:stack-id
aws:cloudformation:stack-name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible with CloudFormation.  CloudFormation does not inspect running resources in your account during an update, it simply performs a diff on the current template vs the updated template and modifies resources accordingly.